# How do I fix the Windows 8 Lock Screen login lock-out?

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

When I lock the screen on Windows 8 using [image: <Windows] + <kbd>L</kbd>, the lock screen background image appears, and usually the clock is being displayed, and when you hit a key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, your login and a password prompt is shown.

However, sometimes the clock does not show at all, and pressing keys or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> will not present anything.

All you see is the Windows lock screen background image, no clock or anything.

I cannot even switch to standby or get the computer to shut down through the power button.
The only way to escape is to force-kill the power by holding the power button and restarting.

However, the mouse is still moving, and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> still turns the LED *on* and *off*.

How can I turn off this security-hardened lock screen that really locks anybody out ?

Has anyone even experienced this ?

Comment: you tried this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/im-stuck-on-the-windows-8-lock-screen/5f36f1aa-0820-4aba-a5cb-5b94aa1a21d4 ?

Comment: I did things like this some time ago, but it is impossible to tell if this ever worked because my problem occurs only once in a while. I am out for the cure for the cause, not for the symptoms, without reinstalling and resetting stuff.

Comment: I'm having this problem too!

Comment: Usually the lock screen works... but when it stays locked for a long time, or sometimes when it is locked automatically (e.g., by screensaver), when I try to login again, it is in the lock screen background (rainbow colors in a disc), without the clock.

The mouse moves, but clicks won't do nothing. Enter key won't do nothing, Ctrl+Alt+Del won't do nothing.

I've noticed that the HDD led will be stuck, either always on, or always off (usually it is blinking). The only thing that works is a complete shutdown of the PC (holding the power-off button for 8 seconds).

Comment: Here is another related question at Microsoft forums: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-pro-crashes-on-sleep/dcc09c56-1a1e-42da-baf1-c13e8c1d7732

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem apparently introduced in Windows 8, and you are far from the only one to
suffer from it: googling for this problem got back 220 000 answers!

There are apparently several reasons for it happening and no one really knows why.
I list below some workarounds that might work, or not (excepting the one
advising disabling the Lock screen completely).

In the article [System Freezes on Windows 8 Lock Screen](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/444a8200-8dd1-4782-898e-d7d3f5dd422b/system-freezes-on-windows-8-lock-screen),
the following registry hack disables the lock screen image and just shows the password box:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
"NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001
```

Another advice in the same article was to update the BIOS.

In the article [How do I stop windows 8.1 from freezing when the screen locks](https://superuser.com/questions/682059/how-do-i-stop-windows-8-1-from-freezing-when-the-screen-locks),
disabling sleep has fixed the problem, so perhaps the problem there occurred when Windows
went to sleep inside the Lock screen.

In the article [Random freeze issue since upgrading to win 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/34141-random-freeze-issue-since-upgrading-win-8-1-a-2.html),
one solution was to turn off Store App automatic update.
Another solution was to [Use DISM to Fix Component Store Corruption](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html).

I have even found one article where using the mouse wheel fixed the freeze.

Answer (score -1):

- hit <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- type in `netplwiz`
- untick the option up top
- press apply
- confirm dreaded password one more time
- hit okay!

Comment: The problem should be solved without disabling functionality (i.e., locking the computer with a password should still work).